# What is the delay in ILINet case reporting?

Tags: covid-19, influenza, united-states, center-disease-control

In the "Opening Up America Again" White House [presentation](https://youtu.be/v_2F0a9sjko?t=7798) they showed this graph

[image]

How up-to-date is that precipitous drop though we can see there?

I found the relevant [CDC page](https://www.cdc.gov/flu/weekly/index.htm) (there's a similar graph half-way down the pretty long page), but they don't mention any delay in ILINet reporting, unlike [e.g.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47265/has-the-number-of-pneumonia-deaths-in-the-us-dramatically-dropped-in-2020) NVSS death reporting.

So, is it really the case that in the US as soon you go to a primary care physician, the CDC gets your influenza-like illness case report immediately, e.g. on the same or at most the next day? If not, what's the delay in reporting cases through ILINet?

Comment: Was this graph posted before under a different question?

Comment: @GrahamChiu: no, I deleted and then undeleted + edited the question. So in that sense yes :0

Comment: Ah, oh.  I had the answer ready to then find the question gone!

Comment: @GrahamChiu: sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is collected over a week long period of people presenting with influenza like symptoms and reported once a week by fax or internet.  Clearly there will be a delay of some type if reporting is significant by fax.

> ILINet providers report each week the total number of patients seen for any reason and the number of
>   patient visits for ILI by age group (0-4 years, 5-24 years, 25-49 years, 50-64 years, >64 years).
>
> This data is transmitted once a week via the Internet or fax to a central data repository at CDC. Most
>   providers report that it takes them less than 30 minutes a week to compile & report their data. In
>   addition, ILINet providers collect respiratory specimens from patients with ILI to send to the Missouri
>   State Public Health Laboratory for testing.

https://health.mo.gov/living/healthcondiseases/communicable/influenza/pdf/ilinet-program-description.pdf

Comment: I see, so while there is a delay, there's no "trickle in" like for NVSS, i.e. they don't report through ILInet stuff from several weeks prior spread haphazardly over some subsequent weeks.

Comment: So all data points are final (once reported) in ILInet.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a symptom tracker, and not a disease tracker.